# How to perform a line of code if any of a number of conditions are true?

Tags: php, if-statement

Say I'm doing the following:

```
if (foo):
    echo 'foo';
    echo ' | ';
elseif (bar):
    echo 'bar';
    echo ' | ';
elseif (baz):
    echo 'baz';
    echo ' | ';
endif;
echo 'something else';
```

I'd like to avoid repeating the `echo ' | ';` line, but perform it when *any* of the conditions is true, and not if they aren't. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @SteveO'Connor: See [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: @SteveO'Connor It's valid PHP. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Isaac No, my mistake as Tim mentioned it's valid - it was just new to me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$display = true;
if (foo):
    echo 'foo';
elseif (bar):
    echo 'bar';
elseif (baz):
    echo 'baz';
else:
    $display = false;
endif;
if($display):
    echo ' | ';
endif;
echo 'something else';
```